# elasticsearch date type mapping conflict

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a field I am storing date information in.  The field is in conflict at the moment.  As far as I can tell there are three kinds of values:

- some documents don't have the field
- some documents have the field like this in the JSON:

  - "timestamp": "2019-03-01T23:32:28Z"
- other documents have the field like this in the JSON:

  - "timestamp": "1551206688760"

I want to fix the conflict.

I've tried doing a wildcard search and I get the following error:

`failed to parse date field [*] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]`

I have two questions, ultimately.

1) Is the core problem causing the conflict that when I tried to represent the timestamp in epoch_millis that I used a string rather than a number?  IOW, `"timestamp": 1551206688760` would have been good?

2) What is the proper way to fix this without simply tossing all the data out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you will need to reindex.

1. Create new index [with date mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) to provide multiple formats

> "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"

2. [Reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) your data
3. Use [aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html)

Comment: Does the conflict come down to the fact that my epoch_millis was between quotes and thus not recognized as a long?

Comment: If you did not have mapping then ES will try to dynamically map depends on first document. You can get your index mapping using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html